# Loading fact table with SCD type 2 dimension

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse

I have got a dimension tables with 1 million records which is SCD type 2.I am using pentaho Dimension lookup step for populating this dimension table. I am getting a version number,start date and end date. Now I want to populate the fact table based on the scd type2. What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'Dimension lookup/update' step for looking up the surrogate id ('Technical key field'), based on the natural key(s) ('Keys') and timestamp ('Stream Datefield'). Uncheck 'Update the dimension' if you only do lookup.